Why offset in LOAD program header does not match the offset in address space?
I have an ELF header like this:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align

  LOAD           0x002dd0 0x0000000000003dd0 0x0000000000003dd0 0x000250 0x000258 RW  0x1000

Which is supposed to map these sections:
.init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 

When I do readelf -l program I can see that this section indeed begin with address 0x002dd0:
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  (...)
  [20] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      0000000000003dd0 002dd0 000008 08  WA  0   0  8
  [21] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      0000000000003dd8 002dd8 000008 08  WA  0   0  8
  [22] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         0000000000003de0 002de0 0001e0 10  WA  7   0  8
  [23] .got              PROGBITS        0000000000003fc0 002fc0 000028 08  WA  0   0  8
  [24] .got.plt          PROGBITS        0000000000003fe8 002fe8 000028 08  WA  0   0  8
  [25] .data             PROGBITS        0000000000004010 003010 000010 00  WA  0   0  8
  [26] .bss              NOBITS          0000000000004020 003020 000008 00  WA  0   0  1

But when I launch the process and look the pmap output, it shows that this segment offset starts at 0x003000 instead of 0x002dd0:
         Address Perm   Offset   Inode Size Rss Anonymous  Mapping
    63a2b2ccb000 rw-p 00003000 5243856    4   4         4  program

Why is that? If it starts at 0x003000, is it not missing data in 0x002dd0-0x002fff range?
EDIT: Ok, so I realized that it's because of RELRO, which makes the .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got sections read only, which creates a new mapping. Then the 0x002dd0-0x002fff range is in that mapping and the last segment only contains .data and .bss eventually.
